# set the width for boundfield in spgridview

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I tried different ways to set the width for my gridview clumns but nothing worked out for me. Can some one guide me about how o achieve ths. i am including my code below...

Thanks.

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="gvSearchResults" EnableViewState="true" runat="server"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#f4f8fd" AllowSorting="true" DataKeyNames="ID"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="gvxxxResults_Sorting" OnPageIndexChanging="gvxxxResults_PageIndexChanging">
                        <Columns>
                        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Name" DataTextField="FileLeafRef"
                                DataNavigateUrlFields="FileLeafRef" Target="_parent" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/pp/ll/lp/llDocs/{0}"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false"
                                SortExpression="Name" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Home_x0020_Number" HeaderText="Home Number" NullDisplayText=" " SortExpression="Home_x0020_Number">
                                <HeaderStyle Width="150px" Wrap="false" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                               <ItemStyle Width="150px" Wrap="false" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                             </asp:BoundField>
                             <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone_x0020_Number" HeaderText="Phone Number" NullDisplayText=" " SortExpression="Phone_x0020_Number">
                               <HeaderStyle Width="150px" Wrap="false" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                               <ItemStyle Width="150px" Wrap="false" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                             </asp:BoundField>


                        </Columns>

                    </SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the [SPBoundField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spboundfield.aspx) control instead?   Try setting the `SPBoundField.ControlStyle.Width` property.